# Excel statement with IF/AND/NOT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to come up with a statement that would tell me when cells in a column are missing a "/" **and** cells in a separate column have one of two specific text pieces.

I have tried

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A2, "*/*")=0, 
        COUNTIF(B2, "*FD.AG*")=1, 
        COUNTIF(B2, "*FD.MG*")=1), "DAF", "")
```

but that isn't working, I think because it's looking for B2 to have both FD.MG and FD.AG which isn't what I want.

I've tried combining it into some kind of an OR statement like this:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A2, "*/*")=0, 
        COUNTIF(B2, {"*FD.AG*","*FD.MG*"}=1), "DAF", "")
```

but that didn't work.

I tried sandwiching it all together like this:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A2, "<>*/*",B2, {"*FD.AG*", "*FD.MG*"}=1), "DAF", "")
```

Nope.

The outcome I'm looking for is when A is missing a "/" and B2 has either AG or MG, return DAF.

For Example:

| Name | Fund | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Smith/Jane | FD.MG.Red |  |
| Subway | FD.AG.Green | DAF |
| Doe/John | FD.AG.Blue |  |
| Home Depot | FD.MG.Blue | DAF |
| Green/Red | FD.MG.Red |  |

Comment: Better to put few sample data to your post.

Comment: The condition for the first column is clear, what is the condition for the second column, would you word it?

Comment: Sure, the second column contains either FD.MG or FD.AG.

Comment: What does "cells in a separate column have one of two specific text pieces" mean?

Comment: @Jenny see I have posted in answers using `IF()`, `SUM()` & `COUNTIFS()` no need to do any additional gymnastics, using these simpler functions you can achieve your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simpler approach using <kbd>IF( )</kbd> <kbd>SUM( )</kbd> & <kbd>COUNTIFS( )</kbd>

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(A2,"<>*/*",B2,{"FD.AG*","FD.MG*"}))>0,"DAF","")
```

---

Comment: If you change `B5` from `FD.MG.Blue` to `FD.XX.Blue` I would expect empty, but it returns `DAF`. The OP is looking for not having `/` but your searching for the oposite. It works for some cases, but you get some false positive like this one, maybe that is the reason If I am not mistaken. Thinking quick maybe something like this: `=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A2,"*/*")=0, (SUM(COUNTIFS(B2,{"FD.AG*","FD.MG*"}))>0)),"DAF","")`

Comment: Great!. Now it works, I prefer array solutions whenever is possible. It is easier to maintain in my opinion. For your case the following works: `=MAP(A2:A6,B2:B6,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(AND(COUNTIFS(x,"*/*")=0, (SUM(COUNTIFS(y,{"FD.AG*","FD.MG*"}))>0)),"DAF","")))`

Comment: Sorry wrong copy and paste, I meant this: `=MAP(A2:A6,B2:B6,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(x,"<>*/*",y,{"FD.AG*","FD.MG*"}))>0,"DAF","")))`

Answer (score 1):

Under O365 (there are multiple ways of doing it). This is a quick and easy one. It is an array version, so it spills the entire result all at once for the input data. It doesn't require a [LAMBDA helper function](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-lambda-helper-functions-lambdas-as-arguments-and-more/ba-p/2576648) since `TEXTBEFORE` and `TEXTAFTER` both work with arrays as input:

```
=IF(ISNA(TEXTBEFORE(A2:A6,"/")) 
 *ISTEXT(TEXTAFTER(B2:B6, {"FD.MG","FD.AG"})), "DAF","")
```

[image: output]

or you can use `SEARCH`, this approach is valid for non O365 versions:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("/",A2:A6))
 * MMULT(1-ISERR(SEARCH({"FD.MG","FD.AG"},B2:B6)), SEQUENCE(2,,,0))>0, "DAF","")
```

Where `SEQUENCE` generates a constant array of `1`'s, since we have two OR conditions, we need an array of size `2`. Be aware of false positive, for example if you have `FD.MG1` instead of `FD.MG` it returns `TRUE`, but it would depend on your real data, better to search including the last dot (`.`).

Both are array solutions, i.e. you don’t need to expand down the formula.

Comment: `SEQUENCE` is a 365 function. Maybe `{1;1}` or `ROW(1:2)/ROW(1:2)`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 not exactly, you can use it since Excel 2021. Check this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90), but what you suggested works for older versions